# simple time complexity O(nlogn)

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

I am reviewing some Big O notation for an interview and I come across this problem.

```
for i = 1 to n do:
    j = i
    while j < n do:
    j = 2 * j
```

simple right? the outer loop provides n steps. and each of those steps we do a single step O(1) of assignment `j=i` then log(n-j) or log(n-i) since `j = i` step for the while loop. I thought the time complexity would be O(nlogn) but the answer is O(n).

here is the answer:

> The running time is approximately the following sum: Σ  1 +
>   log(n/i) for i from 1 to n which is Θ(n).

Now it has been a while so I am a bit rusty. where does `log(n/i)` comes from? I know `log(n) - log(i) = log(n/i)` however I thought we log(n-i) not log(n) - log(i). and how is the time complexity not O(nlogn)? I am sure I am missing something simple but I been staring at this for hours now and I am starting to lose my mind.

source: here is the source to this problem [Berkeley CS 170, Fall 2009, HW 1](http://vlsicad.ucsd.edu/courses/cse21-s14/exercises/bigO-practicesol.pdf)

edit: after thinking about it a little more it makes sense that the time complexity of the inner loop is log(n/i). cause each inner loop runs n-i times but i double each loop. if the inner loop were always starting at 0 we have log(n) but take into account the number of the loop we don't have to loop over which is log(i). log(n) - log(i) which is log(n/i).

Comment: To add to the answer provided [See Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/74412/how-to-show-sum-limits-i-1n-log-left-fracni-right-thetan) how this sum is O(n)

Comment: Thanks @RSon1234 that is exactly what I am looking for!

Comment: Since you found an answer yourself, please post it as an answer - it may help other people in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I think the log(n/i) comes from the inner loop

notice how `j = i`

which means when i=2 (lets say n=10)

the inner loop

```
while j < n do:
    j = 2 * j
```

will run only from `j=2` to `10` where j multilplies itself by 2 (hence the log) & quickly overruns the value of `n=10`

so the inner loop runs `log base 2 n/i times`

i ran a simple i=10 through the code & it looks like linear time because most of the time inner loop runs only once.

example : when the value of i becomes such that if you multiply it by 2, you get greater than or equal to n, you don't run the inner loop more than once.

so if n=10 you get one execution in the inner loop starting from `i=n/2 (if i=10/2=5)` then j starts with j=5, gets in the loop once multiplies itself with 2 & the inner loop condition  `while j < n do:` fails.

EDIT : it would be `O(n.log(n))` if the value of j started with j=0 everytime & the inner loop ran from i to n

Comment: Thanks Sujal. I am aware `j = i` and log(n/i) comes from the inner loop and number of behaviors you mentioned in your answer.however if each inner loop runs n-i times why shouldn't it be log(n-i). and even if we have log(n/i) why is the runtime o(n) not log(n/i)

Comment: see the last part of the answer, this code runs only one execution for every j which has the equivalent of i/2 initial value, just take a pen & paper and write down a simple execution for n=10 you will see the total steps performed is around 16 which is more or less similar to n=10, if it had been O(n.log(n)) it would be 10*3 or 30 executions.